# PAX-CDI + Drool + @Inject @KSession @KReleaseId Not working

Tags: cdi, drools, weld, pax

The pax cdi + weld + drool not working getting the following exception

WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type KieSession with qualifiers @KSession

https://salaboy.com/2015/10/20/back-to-the-basics-getting-started-with-drools-6-3-0-final/

Answer (score 0):

Posted the solution in this

[PAX-CDI + Drool](http://opensourceappexample.blogspot.ca/2017/06/osgi-pax-cdi-drools-karaf.html)